# Read XML file from containing JAR

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I am trying to read an XML file from inside of my JAR.

My folder structure is like this:

```
[root]  
    src (source folder)  
        [my java files]
    res (source folder)
        xml
            lorem_ipsum.xml (xml file I wish to read)
```

and I'm trying to use this code to read the file:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream stream = cl.getResourceAsStream(path);

if(stream == null) {
    return null;
}

Document doc = db.parse(stream);
```

but it's not working. `stream` keeps on being null when I specifiy `/xml/lorem_ipsum.xml` as `path`.

Comment: and the code you wrote to try and do this is where?  (hint: paste the concise code that isn't working in your question)

Comment: sorry, I accidentally pressed enter and posted the question before  I was ready.

Comment: What does `path` look like?

Comment: instead of `/xml/lorem_ipsum.xml` try `res/xml/lorem_ipsum.xml` (with "res" and without a `/` at the beggining)

Comment: Do your java classes use packages or are they in the "default" package?

Comment: @morgano Nope, that didn't work

Comment: Is the "res" folder on the classpath (and copied into the jar file)?

Comment: I am new to Java, so I'm not sure what all of this means. `res` is a source folder, and `xml` inside of `res` is a package.

Comment: then try this: unzip your jar, see whether your file is there, and then try 'path/to/file/without/leading/slash'

Comment: `res` doesn't seem to be an embedded resource, have your tried using `new File("res/xml/lorem_ipsum.xml")` instead of trying to get the `InputStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted directory structure...

```
[root]  
    src (source folder)  
        [my java files]
    res (source folder)
        xml
            lorem_ipsum.xml (xml file I wish to read)
```

`res` doesn't seem to be an embedded resource.  Instead try using `new File("res/xml/lorem_ipsum.xml")` instead of trying to get the `InputStream` from the classes resource context

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the class's ClassLoader, and use the full path relative to the jar structure, something like:

```
String path = "res/xml/lorem_ipsum.xml";

// you would rename "MyClass" to the actual name of your class.
ClassLoader classLoader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader(); 
InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

Comment: I would make sure that the XML file was an actual embedded resource and/or the res directory was within the classpath... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use *Asset Manager*

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

try {
   input = assetManager.open("helloworld.txt");

          int size = input.available();
          byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
          input.read(buffer);
          input.close();

          // byte buffer into a string
          String text = new String(buffer);

          txtContent.setText(text);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

[asset manager](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/android-read-file-from-assets.html)

Comment: That seems to be Android-specific. This is a vanilla Java project. I don't know who added the Android tag to the question.